# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I have this problem when trying to read a session in another asp.net page.

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
If Session("cne").Equals("") Then
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
End If
```

I'm setting the session in the Default page with this code :

```
Session("cne") = cne.Text
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post some additional code.  Based on what you have here there is no reason for the error, but since it is happening that would suggest either the default page is not getting called first, or there is other code somewhere setting the value to null.  More context will help determine what is going on.

Comment: @ckramer: the error is obvious, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim cne = Session("cne")
If cne Is Nothing OrElse cne.Equals("") Then 
    Response.Redirect("~")
End If
```